# PHP script doesn't say there is an error but it won't send to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I found a lot of these on the side but I don't understand them. Can someone just post the good code and point the wrong things out.

Code didn't want to be posted here is a foto of it

html form
[image]

php action
[image]

If it helps iam using byethost so I could be something byethost related

Comment: You will need to post your code to get help. There's not much we can do with this amount of information.

Comment: post your code and your link also do not help out to know the problem

Comment: Is a foto good too? I got 2 of those with the code, removed the Css of the html form though

Comment: in the photo `[host]` `[username]` and `[mypassword]` are substituted intentionally or this is the actual code you are trying to run?

Comment: The host username password is cuz I don't want people to see my host username and password :)

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions. You should use PDO or mysqli_* . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Your post indexing is wrong. You can not use value of id attrbute with POST. You have to use value of name attribute so change your code to

```
$_POST['firstname'] AND $_POST['lastname']
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things: 1. form should be specified method.

```
<div> 
  <form action="login_action.php" method="post" >
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" >

  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" >
</div>
```

otherwise, the form will be using get method, and there is no data send to `$_POST`. refer to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

As @User7 mentioned. The data index in `$_POST` is based on the input name, not id

```
 $sql ='INSERT INTO login_info(fname, lname) VALUES ("'.$_POST['firstname'].'","'.$_POST['lasttname'].'")';
 if(!mysql_query($sql, $con)){
  die('error:'.mysql_error());
 }
```

Comment: You must understand xD, iam such a web devenlopment nub can you put the hole code...

Comment: What do you mean by good code? These are just minor changes to your original code.